# How to delete images that are not sufficiently landscape-y in BASH?

Tags: image, bash

I use an image scraper which fetches popular images from Reddit that I then use as desktop wallpaper.  But ones which aren't close enough to my desktop landscape resolution end up looking funny.  Is there a good way in BASH to delete all images whose height:width ratio is below a certain level?

Comment: Maybe a question for [Linux & Unix Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: With `identify` from [tag:ImageMagick] you can get image resolution: `identify image.jpg | awk '{print $3}'`

Answer (score 2):

Try identify from ImageMagick:

```
identify -format "%f %[fx:w/h]\n" file.jpg [or files]
```

It will output in the format:

```
filename1 image_ratio
filename2 image_ratio
...
```

So, if your desktop has image ratio 1.777 you can try something like:

```
identify -format "%f %[fx:w/h]\n" *.jpg | grep " 1\.[678]" | cut -d " " -f 1
```

for a list of files with image ratio from 1.6 to 1.899999, assuming ther is no space in filename.

EDIT:

If you want delete "wrong" files try:

```
identify -format "%f %[fx:w/h]\n" *.jpg | grep -v " 1\.[678]" | cut -d " " -f 1
```

for file names outside 1.6-1.9 range. If you 100% shure there is no files with space in file name, try:

```
identify -format "%f %[fx:w/h]\n" *.jpg | grep -v " 1\.[678]" | cut -d " " -f 1 | xargs rm
```